# Option clash for package fontspec

Tags: fontspec, option-clash

Can someone help with option clash for package fontspec?
I'm compiling by using XeLaTeX in TeXmaker 5.0.3.
I get this error and I don't see preview in program, however PDF is producing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cancel}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, tmargin=30mm, bmargin=30mm, foot=10mm, head=10mm}
\setmainfont{Segoe Print}

\setmathsfont(Digits){Segoe Print}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Segoe Print}
\setmathrm{Segoe Print}
\begin{document}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
$y=x^{100}\ln x$
\columnbreak\\
$\leftarrow$ gdy nie ma idealnego działania między funkcjami to między tymi funkcjami występuje działanie mnożenia/iloczyn
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `fontspec` if you’re including `mathspec`. Remove `fontenc` and `lmodern` if you’re using either. Since `mathspec` is XeTeX-only, you’re automatically using utf-8 and also want to remove `inputenc`. Etc.

Comment: The proximate cause is probably that `mathspec` reloads `fontspec` with different options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the unneeded packages. Your preamble should better look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, tmargin=30mm, bmargin=30mm, foot=10mm, head=10mm}
\setmainfont{Segoe Print}

\setmathsfont(Digits){Segoe Print}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Segoe Print}
\setmathrm{Segoe Print}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick respond, its works perfectly. What about this missing fonts, do I need to provide any [link](https://imgur.com/V2c78R8)